# Dynamic price ranges based on min/max price for filtering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

Based on the min and max prices of these items, I would like to create dynamic price ranges for my checkbox filters. For example, if the difference between the min and max price is $10, I would like 2 range filters('$1-5' and '$5 and over')

I was thinking of doing switch case statement but do not know how to implement the price ranges afterwards into the price ranges for the filters.

```
@{var priceDifference = @Model.MaxPrice - @Model.MinPrice; }
@switch (priceDifference)
{
    case int n when (n > 0 && n < 10):
        n = 2;
        break;
    case int n when (n < 25):
        n = 3;
        break;
    case int n when (n < 50):
        n = 4;
        break;
    case int n when (n > 100):
        n = 5;
        var priceIncrement = priceDifference / n;
        <div id="priceFilter">
        <label class="pOne">
        <input type="checkbox" value="" min="1" max="@priceIncrement">
            Under $@priceIncrement
        </label>
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="" min="@((priceIncrement))" max="@((priceIncrement) * 2)">
            $@((priceIncrement)) to $@((priceIncrement) * 2)
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="" min="@((priceIncrement) * 2)" max="@((priceIncrement) * 3)">
            $@((priceIncrement) * 2) to $@((priceIncrement) * 3)
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="" min="@((priceIncrement) * 3)" max="@((priceIncrement) * 4)">
            $@((priceIncrement) * 3) to $@((priceIncrement) * 4)
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="" min="@((priceIncrement) * 4)" max="@Model.MaxPrice">
            Over $@((priceIncrement) * 4)
        </label>

    </div>
    break;
}
```

If the min/max price difference is over $100, I would like 5 range filters. Let's say the min/max price difference is $150, using the price difference dividing by 5 ranges, gets me $30 for the increments. So the ranges would be (Under $30, 31-60, 61-90, 91-120, and Over $120).

Not sure if switch statement would be best way to implement this. Obviously, this gets really messy with each case when you have to render out all the checkboxes. Is there a better way of this doing?

Comment: Are your ranges fixed ? or you do you have constraints regarding creating those ranges ? what if your difference is $3600 ?

Comment: @NitinKabra - the difference won't be more than $500 in this scenario.

Comment: Ok. so ranges are fixed ?

Comment: @NitinKabra the ranges won't be fixed. If the difference is more than $100, I would like 5 filter ranges. For the example, if the min price is 20 and max price is 200, there would be 5 filter ranges. In this case, the difference is 180, and the price increments for the range will be 36 (180 / 5).

Hope that clarifies some things.